# how to specify the contextPath

Tags: servlets, jetty, contextpath

Hi I am using jetty servlets.
I have the following structure.

war/web-inf/web.xml

war/classes/servlet.class (servlet I want to call)

war/*.html

Problem:

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new GreetingServiceImpl()), "/*");
    server.setHandler(context);
    try {
        server.start();
```

Can someone please tell me what is the contextPath supposed to be?
I get http error 404: problem accesing ./

I need help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's the path in the URL after the domain where the webapplication should listen on.

If you set the context path to `/foo`, then the webapp will listen on http://example.com/foo and all pages/servlets will be available there in the `/foo`.

Here you're setting the context to `/`, which means that the webapp should listen on http://example.com. You're also creating a new servlet which intercepts on all requests (`/*`). So *every* request which goes through http://example.com would pass this servlet.

If you get a 404, then either the request URL is wrong, or the servlet failed to start.